# Issue with string Date formatting 19-feb-01 to yyyy-mm-dd - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

I have string date 19-feb-01 wherein the 19 is the year 2019, that I need to convert to format `yyyy-mm-dd (2019-02-01)` but I am struggling with the formatting.

Comment: The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should always be your first port of call.

Comment: The *real* problem here is you're using a `varchar` to store dates. Formatting is something you do in the presentation layer. YOu should be using the correct data type for storing your data. In this case, the `date` data type.

Comment: The second real problem is that you are using 2 digit years 20 years after Y2K. Learn from that debacle - don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Date_str VARCHAR(50) = '19-feb-01';
SELECT CAST ('20' + @Date_str AS DATE) AS Date
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it does thanks you very much @Phong much appreciated